# Unable to print to print using CUPS on Xerox WorkCentre 5755 from Solaris

Tags: printing, network-printer, solaris, cups

I am trying to print on network printer **Xerox WorkCentre 5755** from Solaris with CUPS 1.4.5 installed. Due to lack of any Solaris related information I have set the printer up with manufacturer provided [Windows Generic PPD](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-5735-5740-5745-5755/file-download/enus.html?contentId=116580). Now every attempt to print is rewarded with page containing exactly

> ERROR: undefined
>   OFFENDING COMMAND: ENTER
>   STACK:

This is the only snippet I found in above mentioned *xrwc5755.ppd*, regarding `ENTER` command:

> ⋮
>   *JCLToPSInterpreter:"@PJL COMMENT XRXend<0A>@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = POSTSCRIPT<0A>"
>   *JCLEnd:"<1B>%-12345X@PJL EOJ<0A><1B>%-12345X<0A>"
>   ⋮

I have no idea whether there is anything wrong about it at all. Could this issue be somehow connected to fact, that this PPD file was designated for Windows?

Comment: You might try it as a generic PostScript printer. Looking at how "serious" the device is, it's 100% it supports PostScript.

Comment: PPD files are not OS-specific; a Windows file will work fine under any other OS. As @Laszlo suggested, start with the generic PS driver. That should work, but will not give you access to specific printer features like trays, paper sizes, etc.

Comment: @hdhondt Thank you for your comments. I have tried generic PS with the same result. I guess there has to be something wrong with CUPS itself and this particular installation.

Comment: The error you are getting is PS's action on receipt of an invalid command (in this case the word ENTER). The PJL sequence you posted is sent to the printer to switch it into PS. If the problem was there, the error should be at @PJL as that is not a PS command either. The ENTER must be at the very beginning of the printer output stream for it to cause that error. Try printing to file, and then examine the file with a text editor to see what's at the front of it.

Comment: @hdhondt I printed to file using Acrobat Reader as I could not manage to do it from any other program. Interestingly enough, file produced contains no _ENTER_, yet it fails with the same error.

Comment: So it appears the driver is not the problem. That leaves the queue as the culprit. Try sending the file to the printer with "lpr -Pprinter_ip_address filename". If that works, try creating a new queue that just sends the raw data to the printer's IP address.

Comment: @hdhondt `lpr -P` expected CUPS name of the printer. So I tried `lpr -P Xerox_WorkCentre_5755  -l rozfule.ps` (actual driver was Generic PS) and I ended up with following 4 lines and bunch of white papers.

M%!PS-Adobe-3.1
%ADO_DSC_Encoding: MacOS Roman
%%Title: testprint-1.pdf
%%Creator

However inspired by your idea I uploaded given PS file to the printer via its web interface and voilà it _printed correctly_!
So you are probably right and my CUPS installation is somehow in some strange way broken.

Comment: As the Xerox supports PS you don't really need CUPS. CUPS is required to support non-PS printers: it converts PS into something the printer can understand. In your case you can create a queue that sends the file straight to the printer.

Comment: @hdhondt I created _RAW_ queue `sudo lpadmin -p Xerox -v socket://10.xxx.xxx.xxx` as you suggested and **I am able to print!** Then I assigned PPD to this queue so I can set options like duplex and it is working like a charm now. If you could sum your guidance into an answer, I will gladly accept it.
P.S. I was also able to destroy this queue to the state identical to my initial problem and it seems to be related to some default options I have set using CUPS web interface. I have not pin-pointed which one is responsible, yet I believe I have set these options according to our printer's config.